# Custom function returns true when it should return false?

Tags: php

I have the function below, which accepts an array of IP cidr's or single IP's, like so:

```
$cidrs = array("127.0.0.1","65.87.43.65/32");
```

Etc..

The function then checks to see if a given IP is listen in that array of IP's and CIDR's, whether it be in a CIDR or it be a single IP specified.

The issue is that if an IP doesn't contain a CIDR mask, then it will always return true - no matter what the IP's in the list are.

I'm sure it worked at least once, however I don't know what I changed to make it behave differently.

The function is as below:

```
function testIP($user_ip, $cidrs)   
{  
    $ipu = explode('.', $user_ip);  
    foreach ($ipu as &$v)  
        $v = str_pad(decbin($v), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);  

    $ipu = join('', $ipu);  
    $res = false;  

    foreach ($cidrs as $cidr)   
    {  

        $parts = explode('/', $cidr);  

        if (empty($parts))  
        {  
            if (in_array($user_ip, $cidrs))  
            {  
                $res = true;  
                break;  
            } 
            break;         
        }  



        $ipc = explode('.', $parts[0]);  

        foreach ($ipc as &$v) $v = str_pad(decbin($v), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);  

        $ipc = substr(join('', $ipc), 0, $parts[1]);  

        $ipux = substr($ipu, 0, $parts[1]);  
        $res = ($ipc === $ipux);  
        if ($res) break;  
    }  
    return $res;  
}
```

I cannot for the life of me work out why it is no longer working - I have lost many hours over this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode` will always return an array. Your `if (empty(...` check is failing. Try `if (count($parts)==1)` then `$res = in_array($user_ip, $cidrs)`

Edit: Also, do not break, rather continue to the next cidr:

```
    if (count($parts)==1)
    {  
        if (in_array($user_ip, $cidrs))  
        {  
            $res = true;  
            break;  
        } 
        continue;         
    }
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I used the empty function as it said it would return for an empty array, and in the docs for the explode function it said that if the separator text wasn't in the text to be exploded, then an empty array would be returned. Anyhow, this worked - so thanks!

Comment: On second thought, maybe that break is necessary. Hmm. I have to think about it